# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I ask for help. I am trying to parse several excel files and send data to the database (Java 8). I use jxls, poi, postgre. The intermediate goal is simple parsing and outputting data from excel files to the console. Below are small pieces of code that is used. When compiling, an error occurs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I**
-at org.jxls.reader.OffsetCellCheckImpl.readStringValue(OffsetCellCheckImpl.java:99)
-at org.jxls.reader.OffsetCellCheckImpl.getCellValue(OffsetCellCheckImpl.java:70)
-at org.jxls.reader.OffsetCellCheckImpl.isCheckSuccessful(OffsetCellCheckImpl.java:47)
-at org.jxls.reader.OffsetCellCheckImpl.isCheckSuccessful(OffsetCellCheckImpl.java:60)
-at org.jxls.reader.OffsetRowCheckImpl.isCheckSuccessful(OffsetRowCheckImpl.java:51)
-at org.jxls.reader.OffsetRowCheckImpl.isCheckSuccessful(OffsetRowCheckImpl.java:66)
-at org.jxls.reader.SimpleSectionCheck.isCheckSuccessful(SimpleSectionCheck.java:23)
-at org.jxls.reader.XLSForEachBlockReaderImpl.read(XLSForEachBlockReaderImpl.java:45)
-at org.jxls.reader.XLSSheetReaderImpl.read(XLSSheetReaderImpl.java:29)
-at org.jxls.reader.XLSReaderImpl.readSheet(XLSReaderImpl.java:65)
-at org.jxls.reader.XLSReaderImpl.readSheet(XLSReaderImpl.java:57)
-at org.jxls.reader.XLSReaderImpl.read(XLSReaderImpl.java:40)
-at Parser.getList(Parser.java:36)
-at ProjectActions.main(ProjectActions.java:86)
```

Parser class:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.jxls.reader.ReaderBuilder;
import org.jxls.reader.XLSReadStatus;
import org.jxls.reader.XLSReader;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Parser {

    public List<App> getList(App app) {
        List<App> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
             InputStream inputXML = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(app.getXmlPath()));
             InputStream inputXLS = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(app.getExcelPath()))
            )
        {
            XLSReader mainReader = ReaderBuilder.buildFromXML(inputXML);
            Map beans = new HashMap();
            beans.put(app.getItems(), list);
            try {
                System.out.println(inputXML.toString());
                System.out.println(inputXLS.toString());
                XLSReadStatus readStatus = mainReader.read(inputXLS, beans);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
                System.out.println("reading error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException | SAXException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }



    public List<List<String>> getListListString (List<App> list) {
        return new Converter().listAppConvertListListString(list);
    }

    public void printList(List<App> list) {
        System.out.println("============= START PRINTING LIST =============");
        for (App app : list) {
            System.out.println(app);
        }
    }

    public void printStringList(List<List<String>> list) {
        System.out.println("============= START PRINTING STRING LIST =============");
        for (List<String> line: list) {
            for (String element : line) {
                System.out.print(element + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

main method:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        App app = new App1();
        Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.printStringList(parser.getListListString(parser.getList(app)));

    }
```

Also, part of the service works through pure apache poi in which there is a util class - DataUtil. Using it I read another ecxel file without any problems - above:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DataUtil {
    public static String getCellText(Cell cell) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
        CellType ct = cell.getCellType();
//        System.out.println("ct = " + ct);
        String result = "";
        switch (ct) {
            case STRING:
                result = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    result = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    result = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                result = String.valueOf( cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case FORMULA:
                result = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I tried to install apache poi version everywhere - 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 3.7, 3.6. Does not help. I tried to completely clean up the loaded libraries and load everything with maven. Does not help. Tried to load ALL ALL jar manually. Does not help. Please tell me how to solve this problem, because I try to resolve it for the second day and re-read a bunch of information? Nothing helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in English please, (на английском пожалуйста) or you can use the russian version of Stackoverflow: [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Looking at the error message: you are most likely mixing incompatible versions of several libraries. Make sure you are using the exact same versions of libraries when you compile and when you run your code; make sure you are using the right combination of versions of different libraries.

Comment: @Jesper what libraries for example?

Comment: @Bashir sorry i didn't think about that

Comment: I don't know, whatever you are using in your project. But don't randomly try different versions of, for example, Apache POI: lookup the documentation, make sure that all the libraries you use in your project are compatible. The docs will tell you "this library requires at least Apache POI version X", etc.

Comment: @Jesper I tried everything with the latest versions. The versions were the same in each case. Apparently I don’t know something.

Comment: Did you [try the code from the Apache POI FAQ to check what jar you are really using](http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) (which probably isn't the one you meant to use)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone encounters the same problem, then the solution is: http://jxls.sourceforge.net/changes.html
That is, with Apache Poi (4.1.0) only Jxls versions no lower than 2.7.0 can work.
And of course, all versions of each dependency should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем уверен если правильно понял. То есть вы хотите прочесть данные из каких то клеток Excel файла и потом принтовать их в консоль? Это так?

I’m not quite sure if I understood correctly. Do you want to read data from some cells of the Excel file and then print them to the console? Is that correct?

For my example I have used: org.apache.poi poi-ooxml 4.1.1

This is how to do what you want:

```
/**
 * This class is used to extract data from excel then print it into the console
 */
public class extractingDataFromExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Path to your workbook excel file
        String pathToExcellFile = "./wbName.xlsx";

        //Name of the excel sheet. Warning: sheet must exist otherwise will throw an error.
        String sheetName = "Sheet1";

        //Row and column of the cell from which information will be extracted
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        try {
            //Open excel file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToExcellFile));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Focus on a specific sheet from excel file
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

            //Focus on a specific row
            XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.getRow(row);

            //Focus on a specific column and extract information from a cell as string
            String excelCellValue = rowhead.getCell(column).getStringCellValue();

            //Print excel cell value in the console
            System.out.println(excelCellValue);

            //Saving & closing excel file
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(pathToExcellFile);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            file.close();
            workbook.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kwazarArt please in English, translate your question, and type your comments in English, or simply use the Russian version.

Comment: in English: I have certain excel files, I made xml for them, which are attached to certain columns in excel. All reading can be done through regular apache poi, but the head asks to do it through jxls. Therefore, this method will not work.